# Configuring Lotus Notes for default stationery while replying/forwarding

Tags: lotus-notes, stationery

I'm a long-time Outlook user, but currently due to a job change I'm now learning Lotus Notes. I have some very basic fundamental questions on Lotus Notes.

We use Lotus Notes 8.0.2FP1.

1. The default font is set to Default Sans Serif. How do I change it to Arial? I have created a new stationery, but then while creating any new email, I would have to choose Create New Mail using Stationery. I do not want to do that. Additionally, while replying, I will have to write my email, select it and change the Text to Arial.
2. Signatures - How can I create a signature in Rich Text if I do not know how to code in HTML?

It is perfectly fine even if you were just to redirect me to the appropriate sites, help files etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1.  Go to the File Menu and Choose Preference.
From here, select 'Basic Notes Client Configuration'
In the Display section of the page, choose "Fonts"

Q2.  Go to the File Menu and Choose Preference.
From here, select 'Mail'
In the window that appears, select 'Signature' and you should be all set.

Comment: Denny: Thanks. Q1 was perfect. However, for Q2 I do not find Signature at the place specified. However, I found them at Tools > Preferences > Mail > Signature and edited it with plain text which is kind of OK for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it in MS Word and save it as html, if you do, hit shift-enter for line breaks instead of just enter, otherwise they will doublespace when you save as html for some reason.

You can also use RTF but you may have to modify your notes.ini file.  Not sure for notes 8, but previous versions require you to add lines to the .ini to enable rtf support.